# Add linux tree command output in listing

Tags: listings

I copy tree command output into listing but compile failure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
.
├── ./a.tex
├── ./b.aux
├── ./b.log
├── ./b.pdf
├── ./#b.tex#
├── ./b.tex
└── ./out.tar.gz
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Fail message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\lst@FillFixed@\lst@EC�).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 ├── 
              ./a.tex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace such characters by specifying them in option `literate`. (The one given is a copy from my own code, and may contain some replacements you don't need.)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

% ~~~ listings ~~~~~~~~~
\lstset{breaklines=true,%
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,%
        literate={│}{|}1 {│   }{x}1 {└─}{y}1 {─}{-}1 {├}{+}1,
        frame={top|bottom},
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
.
├── ./a.tex
├── ./b.aux
├── ./b.log
├── ./b.pdf
├── ./#b.tex#
├── ./b.tex
└── ./out.tar.gz
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```